# ISO 8601 week number in C

Tags: c, windows, mingw, iso8601, strftime

I am trying to get the ISO8601 week number with C. MinGW is installed on my PC. GCC version is 5.3.0. You can see my code below. ***strftime*** doesn't work for specifier "%V". But it works fine with the specifier "%W". But that's not what I want. I need the week number of year in ISO 8601 format.

I have tried my code with 2 different online C compilers and they both worked fine. I doubt that the compiler on my PC is not well configured. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    time_t timep;
    struct tm * time_inf;
    char buff [80];

    time ( &timep );
    time_inf = localtime ( &timep );

    time_inf->tm_year = 2008 - 1900;
    time_inf->tm_mon = 11;
    time_inf->tm_mday = 31;

    mktime ( time_inf );

    strftime (buff, sizeof(buff), "%V", time_inf) ;
    puts (buff); //prints nothing

    printf("%d", strlen(buff)); //prints 0

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me - [click](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af8765f61e764251). Note that `%V` format specifier is locale-dependent. Try digging into this because code looks fine - *except it's C not C++*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to get the ISO8601 week number with C

When `"%V"` with `strftime()` is not available or problematic, code can directivity calculate the ISO 8601 week.

---

ISO 8601 *weeks of the year* begins on Mondays.

When one want to find the [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) of the year, often the corresponding "year" is needed too.

The first week of the year, week #1, is the first week, starting on Monday, that has at least 4 days in January - or as code below uses, the first Thursday of the year is in week 1.

Is is possible that Dec 31 is in week 1 of the next year.
Is is possible that Jan 1 is in week 52/53 of the previous year.

```
#include <time.h>

// return 1 on failure, 0 on success
int tm_YearWeek(const struct tm *tmptr, int *year, int *week) {
  // work with local copy
  struct tm tm = *tmptr;
  // fully populate the yday and wday fields.
  if (mktime(&tm) == -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  // Find day-of-the-week: 0 to 6.
  // Week starts on Monday per ISO 8601
  // 0 <= DayOfTheWeek <= 6, Monday, Tuesday ... Sunday
  int DayOfTheWeek = (tm.tm_wday + (7 - 1)) % 7;

  // Offset the month day to the Monday of the week.
  tm.tm_mday -= DayOfTheWeek;
  // Offset the month day to the mid-week (Thursday) of the week, 3 days later.
  tm.tm_mday += 3;
  // Re-evaluate tm_year and tm_yday  (local time)
  if (mktime(&tm) == -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  *year = tm.tm_year + 1900;
  // Convert yday to week of the year, stating with 1.
  *week = tm.tm_yday / 7 + 1;
  return 0;
}
```

---

Example

```
int main() {
  struct tm tm = { 0 };
  tm.tm_year = 2008 - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon = 12 - 1;
  tm.tm_mday = 31;
  tm.tm_isdst = -1;
  int y = 0, w = 0;
  int err = tm_YearWeek(&tm, &y, &w);
  printf("Err:%d  Year:%d  Week:%d %02d%02d\n", err, y, w, y%100, w);
  return 0;
}
```

Output is week 1 of 2009 for Dec 31, 2008 or *0901*.  This is expected per the discussion above and may explain OP's unstated concern with OP's code.

```
Err:0  Year:2009  Week:1 0901
```

Comment: Although I did calculate the ISO 8601 week with some code, your code here is better and shorter. I will switch to this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to write a solution without the usage of time.h and not use (mktime)? unable to use that lib.

Comment: @Joel Sure, given `y,m,d` , either of us could write a mini `joel_mktime()`.  Give it a try, post as a question should it not always work and I am sure you will get great feedback.

Comment: @chux https://stackoverflow.com/q/56671344/2902996 would appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MinGW doesn't provide its own `strftime`, but links in MSVCRT's definition, [which doesn't provide `%V`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx).

Either implement what you're missing yourself or use an alternate implementation, *e.g.* [here's BSD's strftime](https://github.com/moe123/mirroring-freebsd-github/blob/master/lib/libc/stdtime/strftime.c).